# mplayer and "channel element 1.0 is not allocated"

Tags: mplayer

I use mplayer to watch TV streams via rtmp protocol (rtmpdump|mplayer).

I have a problem with playing one stream: mplayer does not play it and writes

> "[aac @ 0xb614f210]channel element 1.0 is not allocated"

into a console. The other streams from the same site play without any problems. How can I mend it? P.S.Sorry for my bad English.